Is there a way to call a variable that is inside a function in Python?
I recently started studying Python, because of job opportunities, so today I decided to do an exercise using what I've been learning, I'm creating a bot for Telegram in Python, then I came across this situation: I need to call a variable that is in another file to the main file. to make the code cleaner, I separated the code into several files, there is a file to call the api, another that is the main file and another with the bot commands, to To be able to call the variables from the api, I created a function, but I don't know if I can call the variables from within this function:
def botApi(SHINEAPI, bot):
    SHINEAPI = decrypt_api_key()
    bot = telebot.TeleBot(SHINEAPI)
    return botApi

And I need to call the bot variable for this decorator:
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def respostaPadrao(mensagem):
    ....

Does anyone know if there is a way?
I've already tried to ask my technical course teacher and he still hasn't answered and I've tried searching but I haven't found anything that objectively answers my question... and I also tried to declare it as a global variable but it gave an error. I forgot to mention that I had also tried to call it as a return function, but I couldn't call the variable, only the function and even if I tried to pass the variable as a parameter it wouldn't work...

Why don't you return the bot variable in the above function?
then you can just call the function wherever you need it.

Assigning to a parameter variable has no effect on the caller's variable. This is what return values are for.

You can declare SHINEAPI global, then the main script could use yourmodule.SHINEAPI. But it shouldn't be a function parameter.

@Barmar I'll try, I'll get back to you with the results...

@Barmar This error returned: Statements must be separated by newlines or semicolonsPylance

That means you tried to put two statements on the same line. It has nothing to do with my suggestion. You must have mistyped your code.

There's a number of questionable things here. You've written a function that returns a reference to itself: why? We already have that reference. You've also written it to take two arguments, both of which your function then immediately overwrites, so why are they arguments at all? Lastly, python functions can return multiple values, you can just return bot, SHINEAPI and now calling your function will return both those things (as a tuple).  That said, there's a ton of tutorials about writing a Telegram bot in Python: it might make more sense to follow (any of) those.

You should define it without parameters and use return to send value outside function
def botApi():
    SHINEAPI = decrypt_api_key()
    bot = telebot.TeleBot(SHINEAPI)
    return bot

or shorter
def botApi():
    return telebot.TeleBot(decrypt_api_key())

And later run it as
bot = botApi()

But you should run it only once because if you run it again then it may do one of things:

raise error because connection with server is already used
kill previous bot and create new one - and previous @bot.message_handler will be lost
create new bot and you will run two bots - and one bot will work with some @bot.message_handler and other will work with other @bot.message_handler - and they will not know which one processes new command.

If you will have to use it in other file then you should import this file to main code, and send bot (which you already have) as parameter.
